# MigraDoc and UTF characters

Tags: c#, utf-8, migradoc

I am trying to force MigraDoc to render pdf in unicode (currently Chinese/Japanese characters) in c#.
Here is the code I use:

```
public void Render()
{
    var doc = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();
    doc.AddSection();

    Style style = doc.Styles["Normal"];
    style.Font.Name = "Lucida Sans Unicode";

    var paragraph = GetLastSection().AddParagraph();
    paragraph.AddText("彤");

    var pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
    pdfRenderer.Document = doc;
    pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();
    pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(@"c:\temp\test.pdf");
}
```

The pdf itself gets generated but unfortunately the only thing I read is a square.

Version of MigraDoc is 1.32.4334.0

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can try with another font, like `style.Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS";`

Comment: Unfortuately that is not the issue - I get square again (different size though :o) )

Comment: The `Lucida Sans Unicode` on my computer does not contain any Chinese characters. Use `charmap.exe` to verify you use a font that contains the characters you need.

Comment: OK, I am getting somewhere - I am able to print arabic characters (thanks @Bally ole idjit), but I cannot find font that contains chinese as well as other fonts in my default Windows 10 installation. Is there any?

Comment: On Windows 10, for example, you can use the font `Microsoft YaHei Light`

Comment: Still seeing square when trying to print "彤" (I don't even know if it's Chinese). Generally I need font that contains all the possible characters (it's for the hotel application - people with various names can arrive) - is this even possible? I thought that this is what Unicode is for...